# Combining frame and tween animations

Tags: android

I'm new to the android development, and working my way through android tutorials available on Android website more specifically relating to animation. Now I know how to apply tween and frame by frame animations, but I can't figure out how to combine these two animations to run simultaneously example of which could be an animating character(frame by frame) walk across the screen(translate).

I tried putting the both the animation-list for frame by frame animation and translate animation under the Set tag of my animation.xml, file and running using the following code.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.animation); //where animation is the name of my animation xml
AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
anim.start();
```

But it throughs an exception at setBackgroudResource.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the animations to the ImageSwitcher only, ImageView is only used to display a single image.